# Copy email from iPhone to MacBook?

Tags: macos, iphone, mail.app, email

My husband accidentally rebuilt my Apple Mail on my MacBook and it seems to have wiped out the folders and local emails. The rebuild gave me a generic new folder structure with emails from the server from the past 24 hours. I do have the emails on my iPhone. How can I get these emails and the email folders restored to my MacBook?

Comment: If you have Time Machine you can go directly into it from Mail & recover any mailbox

Comment: It also depends on the Mail server - if you have iMAP servers or exchange servers, you might check in the could if the account is still working. If so - delete the mail locally on the broken system and sync it down. Best to get a backup, though and proceed slowly - that might be your only copy of the mails left.